# Prove that a function is continuous (square integrability)

Tags: integration, continuity, hilbert-spaces

I need help for the following proof of continuity:

> Let $E=L_2([t_0,t_1],\mathbb R)$ be a Hilbert space of
>   square-integrable real-valued functions on $[t_0,t_1]$. Let
>   $K(t,\tau):[t_0,t_1]\times[t_0,t_1]\to\mathbb R$ be such that:
>
> $$ \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} |K(t,\tau)|^2dtd\tau<\infty $$
>
> Define $A:E\to E$ by:
>
> $$ (A(u))(t)=\int_{t_0}^{t_1} K(t,\tau)u(\tau)d\tau\quad\forall t\in [t_0,t_1] $$
>
> Show that $A$ is continuous.

**Attempt at solution**

Let $u_1,u_2\in E$ such that $\|u-u'\|_{L_2}<\delta$, in other words:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\left\langle u-u',u-u' \right\rangle & = & \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \overline{(u-u')(t)}^T(u-u')(t)dt<\delta^2 \\
& = & \int_{t_0}^{t_1} (u(t)-u'(t))^2dt<\delta^2
\end{array}
$$

since the functions maps to real numbers, we can get rid of the complex conjugate and the transpose. Now consider:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\left\langle A(u-u'),A(u-u') \right\rangle & = &
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} (A(u(t)-u'(t)))^2 dt \\
& = &
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \left( \int_{t_0}^{t_1} K(t,\tau)(u(\tau)-u'(\tau))d\tau \right)^2 dt \\
& \le &
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \int_{t_0}^{t_1} K(t,\tau)^2(u(\tau)-u'(\tau))^2d\tau dt
\end{array}
$$

But at this point I get stuck. I feel like I'm on the right track because I can see this leading to an integral that I can bound by some $M\in\mathbb R$ due to the property of $K(t,\tau)$ in the question and by $\delta$ coming from the assumption $\|u-u'\|_{L_2}<\delta$. However, I don't know how to get this.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think you may have been a bit overly aggressive in your estimation here, because the next obvious step (Cauchy-Schwarz on your last integral) would require $K$ to be in $L_4$ on the square, which is not given.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? I'm not sure I got it. What do you mean by I've been aggressive in my estimation?

Comment: A special case where your estimates put you in a bad spot: suppose $K(t,\tau)=C(u(\tau)-u'(\tau))$. Then your last quantity is a multiple of the integral of $K^4$ over the square, and you don't know whether this integral is finite.

Comment: A different idea: let $K_t = \tau \mapsto K(t,\tau)$ for each $t$, then your inner integral is bounded by $\| K_t \|_{L^2} \| u-u' \|_{L^2}$ by Cauchy-Schwarz. After this the situation should be simple, because you'll have something like $\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \| K_t \|_{L^2}^2 \delta^2 dt$.

Comment: @Ian I don't understand, so is the problem missing an assumption to be able to prove continuity or not? I have troubles with Cauchy Schwarz from time to time, would be great if you could write in math how you would transition from my integral to $\| K_t \|_{L^2} \| u-u' \|_{L^2}$.

Comment: No, your problem is fine. Alright, so we're just looking at $\int_{t_0}^{t_1} K(t,\tau)(u(\tau)-u'(\tau) d \tau$. This is an integral of a product of two functions of $\tau$, so its absolute value is bounded by the product of the $L^2$ norms of these two functions (thought of as functions of $\tau$). To think of $K$ as a function of $\tau$ we have to fix $t$, which is why I introduced the functions $K_t$. Once we've done that, we just get a bound of $\| K_t \|_{L^2} \| u-u' \|_{L^2}$ from the right side of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: But my inner integral has the terms squared, $\int_{t_0}^{t_1} K(t,\tau)^2(u(\tau)-u'(\tau))^2 d \tau$, so not just $\int_{t_0}^{t_1} K(t,\tau)(u(\tau)-u'(\tau)) d \tau$. Isn't this what you referred to as the problem about $K$ not being in $L^4$?

Comment: Your last inner integral has the terms squared, but you got to that as the result of an estimate which was too aggressive for this situation (in the sense that it sometimes gives an upper bound of $\infty$ to a number which is actually always finite). You should not use this estimate; instead you should estimate the inner integral from the previous line.

Comment: Ah! I see, I will try this now and let you know (will update this comment).

Comment: This works, thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we verify that $A$ is well-defined. Let $u\in E$. By Cauchy-Schwarz
inequality, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
|A(u)(t)|^{2} & = & \left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}K(t,\tau)u(\tau)d\tau\right)^{2}\\
 & \leq & \left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}K^{2}(t,\tau)d\tau\right)\left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}u^{2}(\tau)d\tau\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}|A(u)(t)|^{2}dt & \leq & \left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}K^{2}(t,\tau)d\tau dt\right)\left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}u^{2}(\tau)d\tau\right)\\
 & < & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $A(u)\in E$. It is routine to verify that $A$ is
linear, i.e., $A(\alpha u+v)=\alpha Au+Av$. Finally,
\begin{eqnarray*}
||A(u)||^{2} & = & \int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}|A(u)(t)|^{2}dt\\
 & \leq & \left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}K^{2}(t,\tau)d\tau dt\right)\left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}u^{2}(\tau)d\tau\right)\\
 & = & \left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}K^{2}(t,\tau)d\tau dt\right)||u||^{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $A$ is a bounded linear operator on the Hilbert space $E$
and therefore $A$ is continuous (with repsect to the norm topology).